# DialogFlow Google Assistant not storing user data with verified user

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I have a Google Assistant action that has been happily storing data between conversations on the `conv.user.storage` bucket. It has suddenly just stopped working and I am struggling to track down why. The only major change was deploying an `alpha` release of the action. i have checked and the user is `VERIFIED` and it returns old stale data when I do a trace.

Is it common for this to just stop working?

Answer (score 0):

I paused the Web Activity control on my Google account, and then started it again. Suddenly the data persistence worked again. That's not great though. That it could just stop like that?